# Click event on tags of many2many field in odooo 12

Tags: javascript, odoo

I am trying to generate an event on tags of many2many field. For that, I have written javascript as follows:

```
var FieldMany2ManyTags = relationalField.FieldMany2ManyTags.include({   
events: _.extend({}, FieldMany2ManyTags.prototype.events, {
        'click .o_badge_text': '_onClickTag',
    }),

    _onClickTag: function(ev){
        var tar = ev.target;
        var tar1 = ev.currentTarget;
        console.log('FieldMany2ManyTags1');
        if(tar){
            console.log('Test');
            alert('many2many tag'); 
        }
        if(tar1){
            console.log('Test');
            alert('many2many tag'); 
        }

    },

});

});
```

But the event is not generated. can anyone please help me. Why this is not happening? or any other possible way is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
events: _.extend({}, relationalField.FieldMany2ManyTags.prototype.events, {
        'click .badge': '_onClickTag',
    }),

    _onClickTag: function(event){
        console.log('custom _onclick');
    }
```

Instead of:

```
events: _.extend({}, FieldMany2ManyTags.prototype.events, {
        'click .o_badge_text': '_onClickTag',
    }),

    _onClickTag: function(event){
        console.log('custom _onclick');
    }
    },
```

Hope this will useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to change the reference `FieldMany2ManyTags` which is not available to `relationalField.FieldMany2ManyTags` when extending events.